# IBM DB2 Data Studio Web Console Installer

Tags: db2

I would really like to test the Web Console for Data Studio to see if it will do what we need.  However, I absolutely cannot find an installer/download for it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [dba.se] is not google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the full Data Studio installation image. However, Web Console is deprecated. Use Data Server Manager instead.